# Can Cascalog link to external Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, cascalog

I am using Cascalog on Eclipse . it looks like the dependency on hadoop is provided in project.clj file of project like below

```
:profiles { :dev {:dependencies [[org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core "1.1.2"]]}}
```

If i have to include dependency on locally installed Hadoop single node cluster or some external hadoop cluster --how should i do ? 
If it is local should i simply put the "path to hadoop" in place of "org.apache.hadoop" ?
Your ideas would be appreciated.

Best Regards,
Sindhu

Answer (score 0):

Sindhu, specification of your cluster's location isn't appropriate in project.clj.

project.clj is to clojure what pom.xml is to java/maven. Check out the tutorial on leinengen's dependency management [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#dependencies).
You should make sure that the version you declare dependency on matches what you'll be running against.

The cluster you end up running on is controlled in hadoop conf files - specifically by changing the location of your job tracker with "mapred.job.tracker" in mapred-site.xml. You can read about them [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/cluster_setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I could check  on a link found on cascalog guides **Running on a cluster
Developing and deploying a Cascalog query on a Hadoop cluster**  http://nathanmarz.com/blog/news-feed-in-38-lines-of-code-using-cascalog.html you can find the paragraph **Running on a production cluster** and here the copy/paste

1- Copy the sample data onto your cluster to "/tmp/follows" and "/tmp/action".

2- Next, run "lein uberjar" to create a jar containing the program with all its dependencies. Since the demo code specifies :gen-class and has a main method, we can run it just like any other hadoop program. To run the query on a cluster and output the results in text format to "/tmp/results", run:

3- `hadoop jar cascalog-demo-standalone.jar cascalog_demo.demo /tmp/follows /tmp/action /tmp/results`

Comment: Thanks tangrammer,i am following the above method .I have problem creating a jar using leon uberjar. But i am unable to get a jar bcoz i have an error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem .whats is the fix . I don't understand